# Plots are not reflecting month waise on X-axis on some machine while some it coming correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

I am plotting bar chart  using Dash framework, taking input data from Data-frame mainly two field "ready_year_month", 'c_number' . plots are not showing monthly on x axis on one system while on other it comes correctly.

[This is correct image over x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzFgt.png)

while below is default open on another machine as attach below image.

[Here each month are not coming in the bar as in the case above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6POc.png)

Seems it is like zoom of first image, but on another machine it come this as default view. suspecting this could be different screen resolution. how to set Auto resolve of screen automatically for different screen size machine.?

Below is the code snipper for this

```
figure = {
    'data': [{ 'x' : direct_closed['ready_year_month'],
                'y' : direct_closed['C_Number'],
                'type': 'bar',
                'name': 'Direct Count'
            },
            { 'x' : direct_closed['ready_year_month'],
                'y' : direct_closed['closure_days'],
                'type': 'line',
                'name': 'Avg Closure Time'
            }
    ],
    'layout': {
        'margin' : {'l': 40, 't': 40, 'r': 10, 'b': 20},
        "title" : {"text": "<b>{} Direct Closed in {} area(s)</b>".format(closed_count, area_input)}
    }
}
html.H3("Closed Stats", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    # SP Graph
    html.Div(
        className = "row",
        children = [
            html.Div(
                className = 'eight columns plot-settings',
                children = [
                    dcc.Graph(id = "sp-direct-graph"),
                ]
            ),
        ]
    ),
])
```

Comment: This is nearly impossible to answer without seeing the data. Are the dates datetime objects, are they strings? Do you have missing data? Do the dates have days and months and times..etc?

Comment: Hi Devin, could you help this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/66335508/14453993 ? data are also shared and datetime object are MMDDYYYY format in the 'I' column .