# Name of Month is not showing correctly on X-axis if single month data is available while plotting bar using Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using Dash to draw Bar chart in python. when i have data more than 1 month, Bar chart is draw correctly but when i have single month data(here only February month) it show January month also on x-axis while in the data there is no data on Januarys month. [Here circle the month shwoing in the bar but those data not present in below data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf3sO.png)

I Have Attached CSV Data frame sheet. in Chart i am using 'I' Column field for x-axis, while Column 'A' is for CR Count. [Ready-year-month.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fHKE.png)

Below is code snippet for it.

```
    figure = {
    'data': [{ 'x' : df_cr_count_direct_closed['ready_year_month'],
                'y' : df_cr_count_direct_closed['CR_Number'],
                'type': 'bar',
                'name': 'Direct CR Count'
            }
    ],
    'layout': {
        'margin' : {'l': 40, 't': 40, 'r': 10, 'b': 20},
        'xaxis': {
            'tickformat': '%b %Y'
        },
        "title" : {"text": "<b>{} Direct CR's Closed in {} area(s)</b>".format(closed_cr_count, area_input)}
    }
}
html.Div(
        className = "row",
        children = [
            html.Div(
                className = 'eight columns plot-settings',
                children = [
                    dcc.Graph(id = "sp-direct-cr-graph"),
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
```

But when we have 2 or more month data, the bar chat is drawing correctly. why the January month listed automatically even there is not data of January month?

Comment: We cant offer useful advice without seeing how your dataframe is being built

Comment: Can you have look this question if know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583063/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-column-field-of-dash-datatable ?