# How to add hyperlink in column field of dash Datatable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I wanted to add Hyperlink to the first column CR-number, so it should be clickable, on clicking it will redirect to the link.

below is the code snippet of it.

```
html.Div(
        className = "row",
        children = [
            dash_table.DataTable(
                id='datatable-cr-list',
                columns=[
                    {"name": i, "id": i} for i in cr_columns_to_display
                ],
                filter_action = "native",
                sort_action = "native",
                style_cell_conditional=[
                        {'if': {'column_id': 'Title'},
                        'textAlign': 'left',
                        'overflow': 'hidden',
                        'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
                        'width': '60%',
                        'whiteSpace': 'normal'
                        }
                ],
                style_data_conditional=[
                    {
                        'if': {'row_index': 'odd'},
                        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 242, 255)'
                    }
                ],
                style_header={
                    'backgroundColor': 'rgb(153, 204, 255)',
                    'fontWeight': 'bold'
                },
                export_format="csv",
            )
        ]
    ),
```

here is the image of the table, where I wanted to add a hyperlink to the first column. Do we have any feature to add a hyperlink to the dash?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fix with adding hyperlink to first column with below method and add "presentation": 'markdown' in the Layout for Table field

```
def f(row):
    return "[{0}](<link of redirection>{0})".format(row["CR_Number"])
if open_cr_count > 0:
    df_fa_direct_open["CR_Number"] = df_fa_direct_open.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: can you show the layout?

Comment: found it `[{"name": col , "id": col , "presentation": "markdown"} for col in jobs_logs_df.columns]`
upgrade dash needed if not works :)  thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365782/how-to-make-a-tables-cell-value-hyperlinked-in-dash-used-plotly-dash-panda