# How do I render a hyperlink in a Dash table? (DataTable or dbc Table)

Tags: python, html-table, hyperlink, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm currently working on a [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com) frontend interface (python), where I'm loading data from a [Pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) into a table.

**My question is: How do I render a hyperlink in a table?** I would be interested for solutions with both Dash's [DataTable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) component, but also with [dbc Table](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/table/) (Dash Bootstrap Components) which I'm using in my implementation.

Below you can find the simplified and summarized code how I load the dataframe into the dbc Table component. Basically, when the user clicks on the search button, the query in the `State` is used as a parameter for a `POST` request. The response JSON is mapped and here I try to render a hyperlink - so far without success.

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
from dash import html, Input, Output, State
from app import app, backend_api


layout = html.Div(
    dbc.Button("Search", id='search-button'),
    dbc.Table(id="table"),
)


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='table', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='search-button', component_property='n_clicks'),
    State(component_id='query', component_property='value'),
    State('session', 'data'),
)
def search(n_clicks, query, session):
    if not is_token_valid(token):
        return None
    response_json = backend_api.post_json_secure("/api/search/search/", token=token, payload=query)
    json_mapped = map_json(response_json)
    data = pd.json_normalize(json_mapped)
    table = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(data, striped=False, bordered=False, hover=False)
    return table


def map_json(json):
    # misc processing and try to render hyperlink
    mapped = ({
        "Column A": item["value_a"],
        "Column B": item["value_b"],
        "Column C": item["value_c"],
        "Link": create_link(item["link"]),
    } for item in json)
    return mapped


def create_link(url):
    # url is for example https://www.google.com
    # return url  # doesn't work
    # return f'<a href="{url}"/>  # doesn't work either
    # how do I create a hyperlink here?
```

This is the result for now - as you can see there is only text in the `Link` column - I'd rather want a real hyperlink here.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickable Hyperlinks in Plotly Dash DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70205486/clickable-hyperlinks-in-plotly-dash-datatable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution with dbc Table (Dash Bootstrap Components)

```py
def create_link(url):
    return html.A(html.P('Link'), href=url)
    # alternatively use dcc.Link instead of html.A to prevent page refresh
```

### Solution with Dash's DataTable component

Here you have to use `"presentation": "markdown"` in the column configuration:

```py
# example with only one column and row
data_table = dash_table.DataTable(
    id="table",
    columns=[{"name": "link", "id": "column_link", "presentation": "markdown"}],
    data=[{"html": '<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>'}], 
    markdown_options={"html": True},
)
```

#### Result:

[image]